# Vaadin cannot import CSS file

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

So I'm new to Vaadin and all that stuff and I'm currently trying to integrate a CSS-File to my site. When I try to do this though, I get an error after trying to run the gradle-Project:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

  Failed to find the following css files in the `node_modules` or `C:\Users\Sebastian Malburg\Documents\Schule_4\SYT\Wind-2\windpark_REST_JSON\.\frontend` directory tree:
      - ./frontend/table_style.css
```

So obviously the Path to the CSS-File is wrong, but I don't know where to "start" the path. Somewhere on the internet I've read that it starts in the project's root folder (where my build.gradle-File is located), but it doesn't seem to work. 
Here's my class where the Annotation is used:

```
package windpark.windengine;

import java.awt.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.StyleSheet;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Span;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.ListDataProvider;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer.ComponentRenderer;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import windpark.model.WindengineData;

@CssImport("./frontend/table_style.css")
@Route("windengine/tables")
public class GridView extends VerticalLayout {

    final Grid<WindengineData> grid;
    private WindengineService service;

    public GridView() {
        ...
   }

}
```

And here is my Project Structure:
[image: Project Structure]

Edit: 
I've already tried `./table_style`. I think the proplem may lie in the Path: `C:\Users\Sebastian Malburg\Documents\Schule_4\SYT\Wind-2\windpark_REST_JSON\.\frontend` which is automatically used by Vaadin in think. I guess `\.\` is invalid? How would I change this path?

Comment: You should have a `frontend` folder in the root of your project, on the same level as `src` and `target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS file is placed in the wrong directory. You have it under `target/frontend`. It should be instead placed under `/frontend` which exists directly inside your project's directory.

Once placed there, you should use `@CssImport("./table_style.css")` as Shubham noted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use only file name of css, since your css in frontend folder
@CssImport("./table_style.css")
```

Comment: could you pleas check this cheat sheet and try based on project type, file location, version type, path is given  https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-ways-of-importing.html#resource-cheat-sheet

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your help, but unfortunately I have vaadin 14 so I'd have to use `./table_style.css` again. Have you seen my edit? I have a suspicion but I don't know how to solve it...